# RegExp for every word except first word of a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegExp in JavaScript that matches everything except for the first word of each sentence.  For example:

```
This is a super cool sentence.  Immediately following is this sentence.  Super cool story bro.
```

What I need is:

```
**** is a super cool sentence.  *********** following is this sentence.  ***** cool story bro.
```

I have this, which is the exact opposite of what I need (matches first word of each sentence):

```
(?:^|(?:[.!?]\s))(\w+)
```

Can anyone help me reverse this regexp so I get everything except the first word of each sentence?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in decomposing a task into smaller: 1. split into sentences 2. split into words 3. remove first matches 4. flat the matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sd = "This is a super cool sentence.  Immediately following is this sentence.  Super cool story bro";
    sd = sd.replace(/(([\.\?\!]|^)\s*\b\w+)/gm,"$2");
console.log('Result is: ' + sd);
```

This returns a string missing the first word of the sentence. In your example, you seem to want the punctuation mark. If you actually don't, just remove the `$2`.

Answer (score 3):

This regex will return an array of sentences without the first words from each:

```
/\s*\w*\s*([\w\s,;'\"]+[.?!])/gi
```

Answer (score 1):

As another starting point for a regex-only solution, I posted an example on https://regex101.com/r/yO1gL7/2 - as you can see in the right area "Match Information", the groups are correctly recognized (except for the trailing punctuation). However, it does not seem to work correctly in JavaScript.

```
/(?:(?:(?:^|\s+)\w+\s*)((?:\w+\s*)+?)(?=$|[?!.]))+/gm
```

Comment: I had no trouble getting it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/dooobowp/ Always interesting to see how others do things.